# Does Azure service fabric creates separate process for every service

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Suppose there is an named application running on Azure service fabric cluster. And this named application has 5 different services.

Will these services be running in different processes or in same process? And what if these services are not .net services and are executable?

Answer (score 9):

Guest EXEs always get their own processes.

Otherwise, there are two hosting modes available:

**Exclusive Process** - this one is very straight-forward so let's start here. In this mode, *everything* gets its own process. Every replica of every partition of every service instance of every application gets its own exclusive host process. This is my recommended hosting mode because it's the simplest, and that usually leads to much more stability and services that are much easier to debug.

**Shared Process** - this gets a little more complicated. Within an *application instance*, everything of the same *service type* shares a host process. So, for example, let's say you have one application:

```
fabric:/myapp
```

And in that application, you have two service types:

```
service-type-1 (stateful)
service-type-2 (stateless)
```

Now let's say you create an instance of `service-type-1` with 5 partitions and 3 replicas per partition:

```
fabric:/myapp/mystateFULservice1    (service-type-1)
```

That gives you 15 replicas. With a 5 node cluster, Service Fabric will by default distribute things evenly, so you'll see 3 replicas on each node. In the shared host process model, the 3 replicas on each node will share a host process. Inside that host process, each replica is an instance of your class that derives from `StatefulService`. Right away, you can see how this can get complicated. We're using C# constructs to represent replicas - each replica is a C# object. That means they share a process, address space, everything. If one of those replicas throws an unhandled exception and crashes the process, the others go down with it. And forget about using static variables!

Now let's say you create an instance of `service-type-2` with an instance count = -1:

```
fabric:/myapp/mystateLESSservice1
```

Because this is a different service type, it will get its own host process, separate from the first service we created - it has to, because it's literally running different code/DLLs. This one is stateless, so for this instance of the service (fabric:/myapp/mystateLESSservice1) you'll only get one replica per node.

Now if you create *another* instance of `service-type-2`, also with instance count = -1:

```
fabric:/myapp/mystateLESSservice2
```

That's the same service type, so that service instance will use the host process that's already up for the previous instance of that type, because they're running the same code/DLLs. This is analogous to what we saw with the stateful example - each service instance is really just an instance of your class that derives from `StatelessService`, and this of course has all the same problems.

Finally, if you create a whole new *application instance*:

```
fabric:/myapp2
```

You get a whole new set of processes for everything in that application. So application instances are *always* process boundaries.

tl;dr: use Exclusive Process.

Comment: I am not sure if that is true for Stateless service, as only one instance of service can be run on a single node. So, you cannot run multiple instance of same service, and there is no point of sharing the same process.

Comment: The terminology is a bit confusing. A "service instance" is what you get when you call the create command ("sfctl service create" or New-ServiceFabricService). A service instance has a unique name in the form of a URI, such as "fabric:/app/myservice1". You can create as many of these service instances from the same service type (that is, all running identical code), and these instances can in fact land on the same node and share a host process. Stateless services confusingly also have "InstanceCount", which really means "how many nodes do you want to run this service instance on?"